# How to make a shape move up and then come back at the bottom once at the top of the screen in Visual Basic.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, animation, system.drawing

I can get a shape to go down and reappear at the top but I can't figure out how to get it to work going up. Any help?

This is my code for going down:

```
    If shpBar.Top + shpBar.Height < Me.Height Then
        shpBar.Top += 50
    Else
        shpBar.Top = 0
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the code that *isn't* working, which is the important part, so this may be what you have already:

```
If shpBar.Top > Me.Height Then
    shpBar.Top -= 50
Else
    shpBar.Top = Me.Height
End If
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work in both directions...

```
If downwards Then
    shpBar.Top += 50
    If shrBar.Bottom >= Me.Height Then
        shpBar.Top = 0
    End If
Else
    shpBar.Top -= 50
    If shrBar.Top <= Me.Top Then
        shpBar.Top = Me.Height - shpBar.Height
    End If
End If
```